# How does PBFT tolerate Byzantine Leaders?

Tags: distributed-systems, security, consensus, fault-tolerance, byzantine

It is said that **PBFT (or Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance consensus)** is **Byzantine** fault tolerant (unlike Paxos or Raft that are only Crash fault tolerant.)

Based on this answer : [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434525/5029509) , in PBFT ***"a new leader is elected only if there is a suspicion that the old leader is no longer available."***

If it is the case, why is it said that PBFT is ***Byzantine*** fault tolerant (in addition to Crash fault tolerant), when ***a Byzantine leader can always be "available"***, though it is an attacker node.
***I mean a Byzantine leader can still remain as a leader as long as it is "available".*** Isn't it?
And if it is the case, logically, PBFT does not tolerate Byzantine faults.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72868036/781723, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/263194/971, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152796/755, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/131367/19041.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  I've given you this feedback before: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088996/#comment124033019_70088996), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/130244/#comment273321_130244), [3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238421/#comment488345_238421).

Comment: I recommend you don't use so much bold.  You don't need to bold quoted material, or bold the name of a protocol, or bold "Byzantine", or bold sentences that are important to you.